# How to solve TS7022 in TypeScript with Zod's Circular Schema References?

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm facing a TypeScript TS7022 error in a setup involving circular dependencies between Zod schemas. The issue surfaces when defining schemas that refer to each other. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

export const drawerScreenSchema = z.object({
  screenType: z.literal("Drawer"),
  name: z.string(),
  initialScreen: z.string().optional(),
  screens: z.array(z.lazy(() => screenSchema)).optional(),
});

export const screenSchema = z.lazy(() => z.discriminatedUnion("screenType", [
  drawerScreenSchema,
  // ... other possible schemas
]));
```

I receive the following error:

```
TS7022: 'screenSchema' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

This error is due to the circular reference where drawerScreenSchema references screenSchema, and screenSchema includes drawerScreenSchema. My goal is to create a flexible schema system where screenSchema can reference multiple other schemas, not just drawerScreenSchema.

Do you have any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Have you read https://zod.dev/?id=recursive-types?

Comment: Yes, but I can't figurite out this specific case with the union